# Trouble with Python Flask Tutorial application

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to learn how to build applications with Python Flask, and am having trouble with their tutorial at this address: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/. I followed all the instructions (folder structure, files, etc.) but when I run the application on the command line with python, the application does not run when I plug in the web address into my browser. I am very new to Python so any help would be appreciated. What could be going on?

Comment: can you give more informations? which step are you at? what does it say when it doesn't work/

Comment: I went through all the steps and am just trying to fire up the application by entering in the command line my main application file: "$ python flaskr.py" The application begins to run and an IP address is returned, but when I go to the IP address, it gives me an error saying that the page does not exist, just like it did after the very first exercise when we started up the application. Here is a link to a Google Docs folder with all my files organized exactly as they are on my computer: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4qcwfQrgpY0ckNnNmszNl9lMDA&usp=sharing

Comment: oh, and just a pointer, if you plan on learning flask and web dev in python, there is a great book http://flaskbook.com/ that explains things pretty well. I found online python web dev tutorials generally aren't very clear and detailed.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check that out! I've only been learning Python for the past six months, and most of it has been in data analysis, so web development has been tough.

Comment: I also came from a science background. yeah, web dev is a little different from science and math.  udacity's python web dev course explains basics of web dev. https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253  looks like they are no longer free. but you can still try it for free for two weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I look through your code. It appears to be a simple error:

In flaskr.py, move these two lines to the end of the file.

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`

Then it works. The reason is when you run 
`python flaskr.py`

it goes through the file and when it reaches those two lines it runs the server at which point route '/' is not registered. Therefore it gives a 404.